# Delaying javascript to avoid API limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing an app where I have to do geocode a few hundred of items per request. So very naively I just did a for-loop calling the google maps geocoding API. What happens is that my code does too many calls to the API in very short time, so after 5-10 iterations the geocoding API just answers with an `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` limit. Referring to the Google API reference, this happens because:

> The webpage has gone over the requests limit in too short a period of
>   time.

My loop currently is something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dict.nodes.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        g.geocode({'address': dict.nodes[i].location}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                dict.nodes[i]["geocoded_location"] = results
            }
        })
    })(i);
}
```

How can I implement something like a sleep() function to randomly delay the call of the geocoding function to avoid the API limit. I implemented a dumb while-loop but it also makes the CPU cry. Any ideas?

Comment: First question: WHY do you need to geocode a few hundred items at once? You probably ought to rethink that part of your app. [Google Maps API limitations](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing) -- you may need a paid key, or a different mapping API.

Comment: It's a data visualization app, so when I user request something, it's  burst of objects that need to be geocoded. Everything happens from the browser, so there's no problem with the 2500 max request/day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a simple `setInterval`, set it to every 100ms or something?

```
var i = 0;

var setAPI = setInterval( function () { 

    if ( i < dict.nodes.length ) {
        g.geocode({'address': dict.nodes[i].location}, function (results, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                dict.nodes[i]["geocoded_location"] = results
             }
        });
    }

    i++;

  }, 
100); //100ms delay
```

Now you can at any point: `clearInvterval(setAPI);` to stop it from running.

It's very similar to using setTimeout and calling a function as `Engineer` pointed out.

Comment: It's a good idea, but can you provide an implementation also?

Comment: Oops the while should be an if... my mistake - fixed

Comment: You need to care about `i` scope, "to not mixing" response results.

Comment: Yeah completely forgot var i = i || 0; works within a for loops etc, but within an Interval it'll keep reseting itself each time around to zero. Moved `var i` outside the scope it works now. Thanks man

Comment: There is still a problem with the i, as the results are mixing

Comment: Have you tried extending the ms delay? It might take longer on some of the api requests than 100ms to retrieve the results

Answer (score 2):

You can implement something like this,instead of `for` loop:

```
(function nextCall(i){
    if(i < dict.nodes.length){
        g.geocode({'address': dict.nodes[i].location}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                dict.nodes[i]["geocoded_location"] = results;
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function(){   nextCall(i+1)   },100);
    }
})(0);
```

Of course,if it will be exceeded the limit by `'100'` delay, you can increase it.